# Why does having the time in GNU date break "- 1 day"?

Tags: date, unix, gnu

This converts the given datetime to epoch time (seconds)

```
date -d"2015-07-24 11:29:00" +%s
// gives 1437762540
```

Now I want to do the same thing, but subtract a day. Normally, this is as simple as adding "- 1 day". However, instead of subtracting a day, it actually adds a day.

```
date -d"2015-07-24 11:29:00 - 1 day" +%s
// gives 1437848940 (notice, this value is great than the one above)
```

If I take away the time portion from my timestamp it works great. The time portion seems to break it however. I know I can do this in two separate steps and avoid this problem. However, I was hoping to do it in one command. Is this possible?

Comment: try explicitly adding your local timezone ie. date -d"2015-07-24 11:29:00 YOURTZ -1 day" on the second part

Comment: If we replace '-1 day' with 'day ago', it seems to work, weird!

Comment: Recommended to specify the timezone as a UTC offset (e.g. `-0400` for Eastern Daylight Time) to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: `date` is not part of bash -- it's a generic UNIX tool (though the functionality in question is specific to the GNU version). It'd behave the same way if you called it from Java or Python. Using the bash tag for a tool available from any shell or without a shell at all is inappropriate.

Comment: You could probably do: `tz=$(date +%Z); date -d "2015-07-24 11:29:00 $tz -1 day" +%s`

Comment: Thanks to the comments/editors clearing up the specifics of this being GNU and date and such - I'm a bit of a novice in this area.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is some ambiguity in the `date` command about how to interpret the `- 1` token in your date string. It resolves it as a time zone specification

```
$ date -d "2015-07-24 11:29:00 -1"
Fri Jul 24 08:29:00 EDT 2015

$ date -d "2015-07-24 11:29:00 UTC-1"
Fri Jul 24 08:29:00 EDT 2015

$ date -d "2015-07-24 11:29:00 - 2"
Fri Jul 24 09:29:00 EDT 2015

$ date -d "2015-07-24 11:29:00 UTC-2"
Fri Jul 24 09:29:00 EDT 2015

$ TZ=UTC date -d "2015-07-24 11:29:00 -1"
Fri Jul 24 12:29:00 UTC 2015
```

(your results may vary depending on your `TZ` setting)

The `day` part is then interpreted to mean *add* one day

```
$ date -d "2015-07-24 11:29:00 - 1 day"
Sat Jul 25 12:29:00 EDT 2015

$ date -d "2015-07-24 11:29:00 UTC-1 + 1 day"
Sat Jul 25 12:29:00 EDT 2015
```

Add a timezone spec to your date string, as @amdixon suggests, to resolve the ambiguity and get the expected results.

Comment: Since I live in California, and since I don't want to have to change the script every 6 months, is there a way of specifying the timezone to be "America/Los_Angeles" instead of PST/PDT?  (I know for the subtraction that it works fine using just UTC, thanks, but I don't want to confuse future people who might look at the script)

Answer (score 0):

For reference, the GNU coreutils info page for "Date input formats": https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Date-input-formats.html

I don't have a precise answer. I do know that free-form datetime parsing is hard. Playing around with date:

```
$ date -d"2015-07-24 11:29:00 - 1 day" "+%F %T"
2015-07-25 08:29:00
$ date -d"2015-07-24  - 1 day" "+%F %T"
2015-07-23 00:00:00
$ date -d"11:29:00 - 1 day" "+%F %T"
2015-07-25 08:29:00
$ date -d"2015-07-24  - 1 day 11:29:00" "+%F %T"
2015-07-23 11:29:00
```

So, subtracting a day from a date seems to work, but subtracting a day from a time is problematic.